# Java: Highscore system

Tags: java, http, ftp

I'm working on a project and I'm told to implement a `highscore` system. I do not have super long time so a relative easy method would be awesome.

The game is in `java`, both for the `Android` and `Computer` platform.

Should I use FTP, txt file HTTP or another?

Cheers!

Comment: You need about 3000% more detail.  What code do you have?  What have you tried?  Is this homework?

Comment: FTP, Text File, HTTP? You're connecting to a server to update a leaderboard or something? what do you have in mind about this? please describe your current situation, what you try to achieve and what do you have now, otherwise we're not going to be able to comprehend the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable method would be to create a simple API. If you supply FTP credentials with your app, chances are it will be hacked.

If you create a simple HTTP API, you can assign a unique API key to every client, and if someone uses it for spam or whatever, you can just ban them without affecting the others. (See, you store valid API keys in a database, or whatever.)

Generally speaking, almost anything that doesn't use a unique, per-client authentication can be abused, if you store FTP or SQL connection data in your app, you're going to have a bad time.